# Создавая новый пост в October CMS в кастомном компоненте как выбрать и задать категорию с нужным именем?

Tags: laravel, php7, october, octobercms

В October CMS сделал компонент для создания новых постов в плагине blog с FrontEnd формы, получилось заполнить все поля, но выбрать категорию из созданных/существующих не получается, с помощью этой строки `$post->categories = true;` получилось выбрать стандартную категорию *Uncategorized*, но вот не могу понять как выбрать созданную мной категорию.
Вот собственно весь простенький код срабатывающий при нажатии на кнопку формы:

```
public function onSend() {

    $now = Carbon::now();

    $post = new Post();

    $post->title = Input::get('post-title');

    $post->slug = $post->title;

    $post->categories = true;

    $post->published = true;

    $post->published_at = $now;

    $post->content = Input::get('post-text');

    $post->save();

}
```

Comment: А причем тут laravel (теги...)? Добавьте scheme таблицы постов, как вы связываете категорию? Как вы её с фронта передаёте...

Comment: Мне не надо категории с фронта передавать, мне надо взять нужную категорию из созданных, вставить в этот код и чтобы посты в нее пулялись. Проблема в том что я не знаю как найти нужную мне категорию например под именем "test", по имени искать или id, я в php ноль, так что сорян если туплю, но очень хочу освоить эту cms

Comment: Во-первых, если вы в php ноль то начинать с cms не очень умно, во-вторых, как категории хранятся то? если они в другой таблице - то по названию можно, если enum - и искать не нужно. Так много вопросов и...

Comment: Категории хранятся в таблице rainlab_blog_posts_categories, связь постов с категориями М:М (многие ко многим). В моем случае после создания поста по идее можно привязать к нему любую категорию методами attach или sync, но как именно сделать нужную мне категорию true в post я не знаю, не понимаю как записать